# Confusing trigonometric double angle identity?

Tags: trigonometry, angle

How can I arrange $\sin^22x+3\sin^2x=3$ so that $\sin x=a/b$ or something similar.

Comment: $sin2x=2sinxcosx$ so in your case $4sin^2xcos^2x$. If you then convert $cos^2x$ into $1-sin^2x$, then you have a polynomial degree in terms of $sin^2x$

Comment: @user270816: Plug $x=0$ in your identity and check again.

Comment: Indeed, is this supposed to be an identity or just an equation?

Comment: Sure, must be an equation. That's what happens when one starts to use unfamiliar words at random.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\sin^2 2x+3\sin^2x=3$$
$$ \Rightarrow (2\sin x\cos x)^2 + 3\sin^2x - 3 = 0$$
$$ \Rightarrow 4\sin^2x\cos^2x + 3\sin^2x - 3 = 0$$
$$ \Rightarrow 4\sin^2x(1-\sin^2x) + 3\sin^2x - 3 = 0$$
$$ \Rightarrow 4\sin^2x-4\sin^4x + 3\sin^2x - 3 = 0$$
$$ \Rightarrow -4\sin^4x + 7\sin^2x - 3 = 0$$
Now make the substitution $\sin^2x = u$
$$ \Rightarrow -4u^2 + 7u - 3 = 0$$
$$ \Rightarrow -(u-1)(4u-3)=0$$
$$ \Rightarrow -(u-1)(4u-3)=0$$
$$ \Rightarrow u=1, 4u-3=0$$
$$ \Rightarrow \sin^2x=1$$
$$ \Rightarrow \sin x=1,\ \sin x=-1$$
$$ \Rightarrow x=\frac{\pi}{2}+2\pi n_1, \,\,x = \pi n_2 - \frac{\pi}{2}\,\,**$$
$$4u-3=0 \Rightarrow 4u=3$$
$$\Rightarrow u = \frac{3}{4} = \sin^2x$$
$$\Rightarrow \sin x = \pm \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$$
$$\Rightarrow \sin x = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$$
$$\Rightarrow x = \frac{2\pi}{3}+2\pi n_3, \,\, x = \frac{\pi}{3}+2\pi n_4 \,\,**$$
$$\sin x = -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$$
$$\Rightarrow x = \frac{4\pi}{3}+2\pi n_5, \,\, x = \frac{5\pi}{3}+2\pi n_6\,\,**$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

You can use $\sin^2 2x+3\sin^2x=3\iff1-\cos^22x+3\cdot\frac{1}{2}(1-\cos 2x)=3$

$\hspace{2.3 in}\iff2\cos^2 2x+3\cos2x+1=0$